# Creating combinations without repetitions

Tags: matlab, cell, combinations

I have so far the following code:

```
data = xlsread('filename');

% 1000 samples without replacement
% each element of y contains 10 values without repetition
y = cell(10,1000);
for i = 1:1000
y{i} = datasample(data,10,'Replace',false);
end
```

Now I dont want to have the same vector twice in the cell y, and by twice I also mean vectors like `[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]` and `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 9]`, i.e the ordering of the elements does not matter, but if 2 vectors contain the same elements I want one to be deleted. How do I do that? Is there alternatively a way to sample some of combinations without replacement from data? Data contains 171 values, and all of the combinations without replacement would probably be some milions, whereas I basically only need around 1000 combinations without replacement.. Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `x` be `data`?

Comment: Have you looked at `randsample`?  http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html.  Also, take a look at `randperm`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html